# Cannot bulk load because the file could not be opened. Operating system error code 67

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to use the bulk insert option to pass an XML file into my database. This error keeps coming up

> Cannot bulk load because the file could not be opened. Operating system error code 67

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tmpAccounting_CustomerPayments;
BULK INSERT tmpAccounting_CustomerPayments   
   FROM '\\195.184.11.244\WMS-2017\EDIData\ImportFile.bcp'   
   WITH (FORMATFILE = '\\195.184.11.244\WMS-2017\EDIData\ImportFormat.xml');

Select * from tmpAccounting_CustomerPayments
```

Comment: Well, at the operating system level it's _System error 67 has occurred. The network name cannot be found_ So does the SQL Server have network access to 195.184.11.244? Does the account under which the SQL Server service is executing have share and file system permissions in the WMS-2017 share and on the subordinate folder and files?

Comment: Thank you, I grant permission and it worked.